# Is there a way to submit podcasts to Spotify & iTunes via API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify, itunes

I want to make an application which will automatically upload RSS feed to spotify and iTunes programatically, so that podcast will be available on these platforms as well.

I couldn't find anything in their docs & on the internet. Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: https://podcasters.apple.com/support/897-submit-a-show not sure if you can do it programmatically though

Comment: @evolutionxbox I saw this, but I think this is the manual way of doing it. I need API of some sort that I can use to do this programatically...

Comment: As I said, [I don't think apple provide an API for this sort of thing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/).

Comment: Have you tested if it's possible after all?

Comment: Yes, but no luck @NikitasIO